# edit only the first entity inside an embedded collection

Tags: symfony

I have a parent entity called Publisher and a child entity called User with a ManyToMany relation.

Inside the publisher form, I want to create/edit also the first user, which I achieve like this:

```
$builder
  ->add('title')
  ->add('users', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new UserType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
  ))
```

and in my twig template, I do

```
            {{ form_row(edit_form.users.0.firstname) }}                 
            {{ form_row(edit_form.users.0.lastname) }}
            {{ form_row(edit_form.users.0.email) }}
```

This obviously only works as long as there is just one user assigned to the publisher, because otherwise symfony tries to validate the other users as well, whose data is missing.

Can someone give me a hint how to edit only the first user item in the collection from the publisher form?

Comment: Could you not add a options element to your users collection builder, ref: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#options  You could set it as `mapped => false` and deal with it how you like in your controller

Comment: Maybe add a Publisher::firstUser property and not deal with a collection at all.  I am assuming that you are explicitly indexing your user objects otherwise the notion of a 'first user' makes no sense.

Comment: @Cerad: Isn't users[0] always the first record of the publisher_user join table? I wan't to get the user that was first attached to the publisher, how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field `users` "rendered" after having displayed the firt user:

```
{{ form_row(edit_form.users.0.firstname) }}                 
{{ form_row(edit_form.users.0.lastname) }}
{{ form_row(edit_form.users.0.email) }}
{% do edit_form.users.setRendered %}
```

With `setRendered`, Symfony2 won't try to validate the next users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already used setRendered, it supresses other fields, but doesn't seem to cancel validation...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using Cerad's solution by introducing a getter and setter for the first user.

```
  public function setFirstUser($user)
  {
    $this->users[0] = $user;

    return $this;
  }

  public function getFirstUser()
  {
    return $this->users[0];
  }
```

and in the form doing this

```
$builder
  ->add('title')
  ->add('firstUser', new UserType())
```

and calling the fields of the firstUser in the twig template The setRendered line just supresses other properties of the user object.

```
{{ form_row(edit_form.firstUser.firstname) }}
{{ form_row(edit_form.firstUser.lastname) }}
{{ form_row(edit_form.firstUser.email) }}
{% do edit_form.firstUser.setRendered %}
```

EDIT: because of Cerads feedback about the non-deterministic ordering of SQL rows I chose to create a real property "adminUser", which is a OneToOne relation to the first user attached to the entity.

Comment: Just remember that this is no guarantee that $users[0] will always be the same user unless you use the index by property in your mappings.

Comment: Isn't user[0] always the first record from the publisher_user join table? I want the user that was first attached to the publisher. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: sql database tables are inherently un-ordered.  There is no such thing as the "first" row in a table.  It's a common mistake to assume that the first record entered is always the first record retrieved. You need to always sort or use the index by modifier to ensure which record is loaded first.